# Глобальный using для Razor View

Tags: asp.net, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Есть библиотека, в которой присутствует статический класс с generic аргументами. В коде на C# я пишу следующее:

```
using MyLib = Lib<User, Condition, ...>;
...
MyLib.SomeFunction();
```

Есть необходимость использовать как модель в **View** тип, описанный в классе `Lib<..>`, однако не очень хочется писать в каждом View'e, который использует типы из `Lib<...>` что-то типа

```
@model Lib<User, Condition, ...>.MyType
```

Ибо если вдруг понадобится добавить/удалить очередной generic параметр в Lib - придется менять это во всех View'aх, которых может быть не один десяток.

Можно ли объявить глобальный `using` вида `MyLib = Lib<...>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю такого способа. Но, на мой взгляд, вы выбрали путь во тьму.

> если вдруг понадобится
> добавить/удалить очередной generic
> параметр в Lib - придется менять это
> во всех View'aх, которых может быть не
> один десяток.

Здесь вы зрите прям в корень, но только решение странное. Сделайте соответствующую ViewModel и используйте её. Так вы отвяжите ваши View от указанной библиотеки и локализуете возможные изменения.

Comment: Я пишу базовую библиотеку для сайта. Она отвечает за базовые элементы (пользователи, группы, награды, условия назначения групп / выдачи наград и т.д.). Я там использую ORM, который, собственно, генерирует схему баз основываясь на типе переданного ему класса. Мне нужно иметь возможность "дополнять" базовые классы (например, пользователя), при этом должен знать о новом типе и intellisense (для подсказок), так что, единственный способ - это generic аргументы.

Comment: 1) "Я пишу базовую библиотеку для сайта. Она отвечает за базовые элементы". Отлично, есть BL
2) "Я там использую ORM, который, генерирует схему баз основываясь на типе переданного ему класса." Шик, думаю это DL Code First
3) "Мне нужно иметь возможность "дополнять" базовые классы". Проект развивается, от этого никто не застрахован)))
4)"единственный способ - это generic аргументы". Не понял, почему??

Но, ваш сайт -- ваш выбор. Однако наличие некого "супер-дженерикового" мега-провайдера может в последствии стать проблемой. Кейс: если вас сайт "выстрелит", разрезание его на сервисы будет болью

Comment: @buratino, 2) Я использую самописный легкий ORM, который преобразовывает Expression в SQL. 3) В том и дело, что проект не один, а несколько. Я пишу эту библиотеку как раз для того, чтобы вносить изменения в текущие или создавать новые проекты можно было как можно проще. Чтобы мне не приходилось делать одно и то же на разных проектах. 4) Потому что мне нужно, чтобы "базовая" библиотека знала о "измененном типе". При этом должен корректно работать Intellisense (базовая библиотека может содержать переменные, аргументы или возвращать "измененный тип"). Лучшего способа я не придумал.